# Receiving restricted stock units as a dual citizen

Tags: shares, citizenship, rsu

I'm in the process of signing paperwork to receive restricted stock units at my current company. While looking over the papers, I noticed that they mention that I'm 'a citizen of Canada.' I actually have dual citizenship with the United States, and work in the United States as well.

I've held off on signing them until I can figure out what the repercussions of the paperwork identifying me as a Canadian citizen are.

I am going to talk with the company's attorney to clarify this, but in the mean time, any additional information on this topic would be great. Is there any particular meaning to this?

Comment: Are you not a citizen of Canada?

Comment: I am a citizen of Canada.

Comment: so what is bothering you? It seems like they're stating the facts as they are.

Comment: I'm also a citizen of (and live in) the United States.

Comment: I still seem to be missing your point. What's bothering you? It seems like they're stating the facts correctly, what are you asking exactly?

Comment: I'm asking why it's specified that I'm a Canadian citizen; my assumption is that it has some special meaning in regards to holding RSUs. Why not say that I'm a US citizen? It has to be there for a reason.

Comment: why don't you ask them? My guess would be that they're trying to cover their a$$ in case you don't report it properly to the Canadian tax authorities. They will report to the American (I'm guessing this is happening in the US), but Canadian is your problem. But I can only guess, you didn't post the text you're referring to. I don't think anyone can tell you what they mean just by reading your question...

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to taxes and your country of residence. If you are a full-time US resident, you will generally not have to file a Canadian tax return: "Non-residents of Canada are required to pay taxes only on certain income from Canadian sources."

http://travel.gc.ca/travelling/living-abroad/taxation

If you live in the US, work in the US, and file your tax returns with the IRS, Canada won't ask for income tax from non-Canadian sources because Canadian taxes are based on residency. (Note that the reverse is not true, and Americans are taxed on their worldwide income regardless of country of residence.)

http://www.americanlaw.com/ustxtmp2.html